# Can I obtain method parameter name in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

If I have a class like this:

```
public class Whatever
{
  public void aMethod(int aParam);
}
```

is there any way to know that `aMethod` uses a parameter named `aParam`, that is of type `int`?